# Where is Cedric during the quest "Where is Triss Merigold" in The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

During the quest "Where is Triss Merigold" Geralt is tracking the elf Cedric by the blood trail he leaves.

I've done that, using my medallion to highlight the blood, but ended up at a dead end, some other dead humans:

[image]

So the trail I followed was a false trail. I backtracked but couldn't find any other trail diverging. Where is Cedric?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Cat potion to easily see the blood trail in the forest. There are at least three trails to follow, all starting near the gate between Lobinden and Flotsam. By keeping (mostly) to your right, you will end at human corpses. But if you try to keep to your left, Geralt will mumble something about "he is getting weaker, can't be far now." That trail also ends in someone else's body. But from there turn around and keep to your left again. Cedric is not far from there.

Comment: The visibility of the blood trail is just so much better using cat, making it very easy to follow. This is also noted in the journal, looking there seems to be generally a very good idea.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to Krytharn's tip to use the Cat potion I found Cedric near the lake. Here's a screenshot to show how well Cat works for following the blood trail and a map of the trail you have to follow
[image]

Map of the blood trail:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the noblesse of choosing Krytharn's answer and providing extra info on top.

Comment: I completely agreed with the given map you don't have to drink any cat or dog potion neither have to follow any blood trace just reach the lake where you find the cave behind the water fall. Thanks for providing the map

Comment: don't need any potions.just follow the red line on the map.